# Python Flask: How do converters work? (dynamic routing)

Tags: python, flask, routes

I am trying to get Flask converters up and running as shown in the manual: http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/api/#url-route-registrations

Right now, I have currently four pages defined like so:

```
@app.route('/page1')
def page1():
    return render_template("page1.html")

@app.route('/page2')
def page2():
    return render_template("page2.html")

@app.route('/page3')
def page3():
    return render_template("page3.html")

@app.route('/page4')
def page4():
    return render_template("page4.html")
```

I could not find yet a way to automate this repetitive notation and would be grateful for hints.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[You can create dynamic routes by using converters](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/api/#url-route-registrations).

You'd then define your route like this:

```
@app.route("/<page>")
def pages(page):
    return render_template(page + ".html")
```

Which will accept all of your paths.

You can also be more specific in what you allow in the dynamic paths, such as:

```
@app.route("/post/<int:post_id>")
def show_post(post_id):
    pass
```

Which would accept `/post/1`, `/post/2`, `/post/100` but not `/post/test`.